# How do I ensure that the StringBuilder object is GCed in a multi-threaded environment? (Given that I can't use the using Keyword)?

Tags: c#, multithreading, garbage-collection, stringbuilder, using

EDIT  :- **How do I ensure that the `StringBuilder` object is GC'ed in a multi-threaded environment? (Given that I can't use the using Keyword)?**

I'm using `StringBuilder` across multiple threads and I create a new instance of `StringBuilder` for each thread being called.

I'm concerned about the performance, specifically the memory it is taking for so many instances of `StringBuilder` being created.

Is there an alternative to make sure the GC frees the memory for me? (Like calling Dispose etc.)

EDIT: The `StringBuilder` does not implement `IDisposable`, so I cant use the `using` keyword.

EDIT: I don't want to force the `GC.Collect()` since there are multiple threads running at the same time, and they're sharing resources between them. Some of these threads are lying dormant and are just listening for events to turn active again.

Comment: Just make sure that you do not keep any references to the `StringBuilder` when you are no longer using it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another approach to consider is to have thread specific cache of string builder object(s).
Assuming you are not manually spawning a new thread every time (i.e. threads are not getting created and destroyed, and are instead coming from a thread pool) following implementation of internal StringBuilderCache class in .Net framework may be a good starting point -

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/stringbuildercache.cs

A more sophisticated implementation for reference can be found at -
http://source.roslyn.codeplex.com/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces/Formatting/StringBuilderPool.cs

Comment: Object pools were en vogue about a decade ago when GCs were pretty bad. These days this is a very double edged sword since you mess with the generational GC. Frankly only people who know what they're doing and have profiled the application should do that. Considering the basic misunderstanding about dispose and the fact that we're talking about one builder per thread pretty much guarantees that the problems are elsewhere.

Comment: Still have to figure out how to get it to work with my particular implementations , given that I cam creating the Stringbuilder instance 2 levels down in the function that the thread is calling.

Answer (score 5):

No, `StringBuilder` doesn't implement `IDisposable`, so it can't be used with `using`.

However, it wouldn't help anyway. `Dispose` has nothing to do with the GC. There may be cases where it helps, but it cannot really do anything that invalidation of the reference already does - the only exception being unmanaged resources (which must also be released in the finalizer).

If there is some managed internal resource, `Dispose` could get rid of that reference - however, that isn't really the proper pattern. A `Dispose`d object should be dead for good, so you shouldn't keep a reference to it anyway.

The few cases where `Dispose` is completely necessary are in things like event handlers and `CancellationToken` (though that leak has been fixed in .NET 4.5). In any case, though, the whole point is to get rid of the references, so that GC can collect them - it will not *cause* the GC to collect them.

If you find yourself doing a lof of operations on `StringBuilder` (and it actually causes a performance problem!), you should probably think about reusing the older `StringBuilders` rather than finding out how to dispose of them faster. You can reuse `StringBuilder`s as many times as you like, which is very handy when doing high-performance string processing.

The most important thing when considering application performance, especially on platforms like .NET, is profiling. Don't guess - measure. .NET's GC is actually pretty impressive and rarely needs manual "help" from you.

**EDIT**:

As for your edit, if you're thinking that creating a `StringBuilder` for each thread is too much work, you're probably creating way more threads than reasonable. If you have a performance problem, look into better work scheduling, rather than better `StringBuilder` disposal patterns. There is no reason to keep a thread just to wait for some event - that's what asynchronous I/O is for. So in truth, there really isn't much of a reason of having more than about `2 * CPU core` threads, give or take.

There's no way to explicitly collect any memory in .NET - and it really is a good thing. The only thing that comes close is `GC.Collect`, but it is by far more likely to cause a performance problem rather than solving it. The only place I've seen it being useful is in performance tests. It's also used in WPF, and it causes quite interesting performance issues.

Comment: Unfortunately , I cant control the number of threads being created , but your suggestion is really valid. And yes , we tried using the GC.Collect , that just worsens the problem.

Comment: @UdayMehta Yes, that's to be expected. `GC.Collect` is a horrible idea. What about having a pool of `StringBuilder`s so that you could reuse the old ones as needed? Also, how do you know your performance problems have anything to do with the `StringBuilder`? Was that a result from memory profiling? Is your heap fragmented? Are you using pinned references?

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't have to worry about a object being GCed as long as you do not keep any unnecessary reference to it. Hence, to ensure an object gets GCed, ensure that you do not hold any reference to it. Set any variables referencing that object to `null`. Rest GC will take care of.

Answer (score 0):

You can try GC.Collect();
[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.gc.collect%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Make sure you know what your are doing before you start manipulating GC manually. It does a pretty good job when it comes to balance time vs space performance. Calling GC.Collect will free memory, but will definitely slow things down. What do you try to optimize for?